# Remove parentheses and text in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following in excel and I would like to remove the contents that are in parentheses.  Any advice would be extremely helpful!

```
Amarillo (Texas) Globe Times
Amarillo (Texas) Globe-News
Amarillo (TX) Daily News
Amarillo (TX) Globe Times
Amarillo Globe News
Amarillo Globe Times
Amarillo Globe-News
```

Comment: Find/Replace: `(*)` Replace with empty text. You can also add a space before if you want to keep only one space between " (*)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use standard "Search and Replace". Hit CTRL+H, look for "(*)" without quotation marks and replace with nothing.

If you want to solve this with a formula, use a combination of LEFT, SEARCH, and MID.

```
=LEFT(H23,SEARCH("(",H23)-1)&MID(H23,SEARCH(")",H23)+2,99)
```

Comment: If the target cell contains more than one block of text inside parentheses then use this formula multiple times.  For example, if your data is in cell `H23`, and the formula from this answer is in `I23`, then copy the formula from `I23` to `J23` (making sure the formula in `J23` refers to `I23`, not `H23`).  The first formula removes the first instance of text in parentheses.  The second formula removes the second instance.  You can repeat this as needed.